# Add class of column number using Masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Hopefully this will make sense as it's quite hard to explain but I'll give it a shot.

Basically I was wondering if i can apply a class that contains the column number the Masonry item is sitting in. For example if there was a two column layout then all items that are in the left column would have a class of `1` and all items in the right column would have a class of `2`. Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: it can be done. But, can you show some sample markup or just the table to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Same question here. HTML would be something like

```
<section class="month js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".event" }'>
    <article class="event">...</article>
    <article class="event">...</article>
    <article class="event">...</article>
</section>
```